# Use the Cauchy Criterion for Series to show that the series converges

Tags: real-analysis

Given this series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(x^n)}{n^2}, $$

Show that the series converges using the Cauchy Criterion for Series.

I attempted to solve it using the theorem, 
That is, let $\epsilon>0$, take M=(?) such that for all $m>n>M$, and so on...

however I ended up with $m/M^2$ and I have no idea from here how to make it less than epsilon since there is still that m in the expression.

Comment: Note that

$\left|\sum_{k= n+1}^m \frac{\cos x^k}{k^2} \right| \leqslant \sum_{k= n+1}^m \frac{|\cos x^k|}{k^2} \leqslant \sum_{k= n+1}^m \frac{1}{k^2}$

Comment: Yeah that's what I did, and I ended up with (m-n)/M^2 at the end

Comment: See the answer to finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$\sum_{k=n+1}^m \frac1{k^2} < \sum_{k=n+1}^m \frac1{k(k-1)} = \sum_{k=n+1}^m \left(\frac1{k-1}- \frac1{k}\right) = \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{m} < \frac{1}{n}$$